# Rails 3 Generator - automatically add files to svn

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read that passing -c when running rails generate will add the new files/dirs to subversion to be committed but i have had no luck getting this to work?

```
rails generate model -c
```

Any ideas? Or is this no longer available in Rails 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `rails generate --help`:

```
General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
```

Seems like this is no longer supported, that's my guess!

Comment: Yea, I noticed that as well. Kind of a bummer in my opinion. Any other way off adding files efficiently? As of current, I've been adding them all manually.

Comment: I have never had a problem with `git add dir/` which will add all the changes to every file in a given directory.  It seems `svn add` works the same way.

Comment: Ok i'll give that a try. I tried once a while ago and had some problem, but that may have been an issue with setup or configuration